# How are INI files used today?

Tags: configuration-files, config, ini

I really like the "`INI`" file format:  Declarative `KEY=VALUE`, possibly embedded in named sections.

Further, I like the old "`Make`" style, where values set "higher" in the file may be interpolated into values "lower" in the file.  (I know that's not specifically `INI` style, but Makefiles behaved largely like `INI` files for values, which I liked, to centralize maintenance of values.)

This is still a popular file format for configurations, right?  If you were writing new tools today that relied upon configuration files, you'd use `INI` files, right?  How are `INI` files being used these days?

Comment: .ini's fine for simple configurations. but once you start adding block-level things, you'd want to switch to something more XML-like, like actual XML, or pseudo-html/xml like an Apache .conf file. It all depends on your needs.

Comment: I think there is an interesting question somewhere here, but this is far too general. But I like INI files too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you were writing new tools today that relied upon configuration files, you'd 
>   use INI files, right?

No, I wouldn't. YAML (to choose one of many possible examples) is as concise as INI while giving your configs arbitrary depth (unlike INI, which gives you only two levels).